# sys.prefix not aligned with python version

Tags: python, bash, path, sys

My .bash_profile is void of any PATH, PYTHONPATH, etc. variables being set, which yields:

```
which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

However, when I launch python and import sys, I see the following:

```
sys.prefix
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7'
```

It seems like the my default python installation is confused, and I would like it to be /usr/local/bin.

Thanks.

Comment: Is `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/local/bin/python` a symlink?

Comment: @chepner /usr/local/bin/python is a symlink

Comment: Is it a symlink to something that looks like it matches the observed `sys.prefix`? I'm not sure I see the problem.

Comment: @chepner I am not sure why it's a symlink in the first place. Is my python executable at /usr/local/bin/python supposed to point to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7 ?